# Barra de navegación con 12 columnas en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la barra de navegación se mantenga siempre en 12 columnas con Bootstrap? Sé que debo utilizar `<div class="row">` y
`<div class="col-*-*">`.

Pero el problema es que hay demasiadas etiquetas `<div>` y no sé bien dónde colocar las ya mencionadas etiquetas.

Lo que me ocurre cuando achico el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo al achicar el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LoveMatch<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="color:red"></span></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí dentro irá todo tu código.

Funciona igual, con *Bootstrap* siempre tendrás como máximo 12 columnas, sin importar nada, no hay manera de que las sobrepases.

Cuando tienes un `div` dentro de otro, se obtendrán las 12 columnas del `div` padre:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <p>Este es el div padre.</p>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <p>Este es el div hijo, y tomará las 12 columnas de referencia al div padre.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Alejo... por favor, no muestres tus informaciones personales en las respuestas...

Answer (score 0):

para mencionar que vas a usar las 12 columnas es

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12>
</div>
```

Con eso haces que sin importar el tamaño de la pantalla siempre sea de 12

[Aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) puedes encontrar un poco mas de información de los "cols"